# copy all files and folders from one drive to another drive using DOS (command prompt)

Tags: file, filesystems, backup, dos, copy-paste

i want to copy all files and folders from one drive to another drive using MS-DOS. How to do it?

I am trying `xcopy I:\*.* N:\`
But it copies only files, not folders. So how to copy all files and folders both?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're _really_ running MS-DOS (rather than `cmd.exe` under Windows), you should be using XTreeGold :-)

Comment: Can you rethink the accepted anser for 2018?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `xcopy /s I:\*.* N:\`

This is should do.

Comment: WARNING this doesn't copy all files, use the answer provided by SHABAZ KHAN

Comment: `xcopy` does not always work. I would suggest to use `robocopy` instead, as suggested by [Flimm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877667/1636885) (answer below).

More about `robocopy`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 167):

```
xcopy "C:\SomeFolderName" "D:\SomeFolderName" /h /i /c /k /e /r /y
```

Use the above command. It will definitely work.

In this command data will be copied from c:\ to D:, even folders and system files as well. Here's what the flags do:

- `/h` copies hidden and system files also
- `/i` if destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assume that destination must be a directory
- `/c` continue copying even if error occurs
- `/k` copies attributes
- `/e` copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones
- `/r` overwrites read-only files
- `/y` suppress prompting to confirm whether you want to overwrite a file
- `/z` Copies over a network in restartable mode.

> more flags are found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Comment: I would recommend opening the command application as an administrator if you want to copy as many system files as possible.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, the accepted answer didn't copy all files

Comment: Use this command if you want **ALL** files and folders to be copied over. As mentioned above; this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: opts spell out hickery!

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: got an error "invalid path 0 files copied"

Comment: `xcopy` can't handle paths longer than 256 characters.

Answer (score 31):

Use `robocopy`. Robocopy is shipped by default on Windows Vista and newer, and is considered the replacement for `xcopy`. (`xcopy` has some significant limitations, including the fact that it can't handle paths longer than 256 characters, even if the filesystem can).

```
robocopy c:\ d:\ /e /zb /copyall /purge /dcopy:dat
```

Note that using `/purge` on the root directory of the volume will cause Robocopy to apply the requested operation on files inside the System Volume Information directory. Run `robocopy /?` for help. Also note that you probably want to open the command prompt as an administrator to be able to copy system files. To speed things up, use `/b` instead of `/zb`.

Comment: This does not work on files "being used by another process," like database files.

Comment: Why you using /copyall and /dcopy:dat?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me On Windows 10,

xcopy /s {source drive..i.e. C:} {destination drive..i.e. D:}
This will copy all the files and folders plus the folder contents.

Answer (score 2):

try this command, **xcopy c:\ (file or directory path) F:\ /e**. If you want more details refer this site [[http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm]]