# Deploying ASP.NET application to more than one live server using BAT file

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

Currently I'm deploying an ASP.NET application to 4 live servers that are load balanced manually by zipping and dropping the files to the servers. I would like to know how can I write a BAT file and run from a command prompt to install the application to all the 4 servers. Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Finally is better to write a simple console application to do this job because finally is not so simple if you like to avoid general errors, like unable to overwrite some file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps if only files must to be updated (no the database)

Create a bat file and do that steps, after you have copy the updated files on some directory.

1. Make a file called **app_offline.htm** on your root of your web site, and the site will go offline.
2. Overwrite the new files over the site.
3. Rename or delete the **app_offline.html** file

Here is the command to make the copy [copy all files and folders from one drive to another drive using DOS (command prompt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170683/copy-all-files-and-folders-from-one-drive-to-another-drive-using-dos-command-pr)